# Checking text length in CSS

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I wonder if there's a way to check how long a text will be so that I could use this info in my CSS animation. What's the case? I have a box with a subtitle:

[image]

The subtitle is obviously longer than the box. I have animation fired after a moment that moves it left and shows the rest of the text (I use Stylus):

```
@keyframes title-scroll
0%
    margin-left 0
17%
    margin-left 0
100%
    margin-left -120%

.m-focus
    .title
        -webkit-animation title-scroll 6s linear infinite none running
```

The problem is in determining how long the text is. It can be really any long. At the moment it works with final margin-left as 120% but when the text is longer it will be cut when animation time finishes. Is there any way to make it working correctly, using no JS?

Comment: If only `<marquee>` were not deprecated. :)

Comment: the only thing that comes to mind here is transform:translate(x,y); with this you have "content aware" position/offset for the title

Comment: are you ok with using javascript? or do you HAVE to use css

Comment: I would prefer only CSS because of rigid performance standards of the platform I write for. But if it is not possible, of course I'll do it in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve this `<marquee>` -ish effect:

```css
.marquee {
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great! After some customization it is what I was looking for. I removed 'padding-left: 100%' and defined the final 'translate' dependent on the width of part of the span that makes the text longer than parent div - transform translate(var(--title-overflow-width), 0). It makes the span stop when it's end is visible for user and then begin again.